# How to parse this JSON using SWIFT3

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

Here I want to parse JSON via url. This is what actual JSON data available on url. So I need to parse it and read in my app using Alamofire. But I 'm unable to do it.

**JSON Data in my url.**

```
[{"date":"2017-01-15","USDARS":"15.839023","USDCLP":"659.200012","USDVEF":"9.974801","USDCOP":"2943","USDPEN":"3.359497","USDBOB":"6.859692","USDPYG":"5780.799805","USDUYU":"28.660097","USDGTQ":"7.533499","USDCUP":"0.999845","USDCRC":"547.599976","USDHTG":"64.129997","USDJMD":"128.309998","USDDOP":"46.230097","USDETB":"22.459999","USDNGN":"314.999972","USDEGP":"18.900947","USDCDF":"1227.999527","USDTZS":"2216.999869","USDKES":"103.650002","USDSDG":"6.4077"},

    {"date":"2017-01-16","USDARS":"15.849011","USDCLP":"662.099976","USDVEF":"9.974797","USDCOP":"2936.800049","USDPEN":"3.367975","USDBOB":"6.860284","USDPYG":"5733.700195","USDUYU":"28.749899","USDGTQ":"7.545501","USDCUP":"0.999646","USDCRC":"547.099976","USDHTG":"64.129997","USDJMD":"128.179993","USDDOP":"46.230123","USDETB":"22.39805","USDNGN":"313.999947","USDEGP":"18.898647","USDCDF":"1225.999725","USDTZS":"2221.999959","USDKES":"103.650002","USDSDG":"6.407702"},

    {"date":"2017-01-17","USDARS":"15.882954","USDCLP":"656.299988","USDVEF":"9.974798","USDCOP":"2914","USDPEN":"3.3392","USDBOB":"6.860283","USDPYG":"5771.000017","USDUYU":"28.680621","USDGTQ":"7.533498","USDCUP":"0.999979","USDCRC":"547.080017","USDHTG":"64.120003","USDJMD":"128.580002","USDDOP":"46.200001","USDETB":"22.397891","USDNGN":"314.999989","USDEGP":"18.649708","USDCDF":"1225.000306","USDTZS":"2227.000108","USDKES":"103.750025","USDSDG":"6.407696"}]
```

How do I read it using Alamofire in swift 3.0

Below is what actually I'm trying to parse above JSON data via url.

```
Alamofire.request("myurl") .responseJSON { response in

            print("In Alamofire")
            if let arr = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject]
            {

                if let arr = response.result.value as? [NSDictionary]
                {
                    let val1 = (arr["main"]["USDARS"] as? String)
                    print(val1)
                    //It does not print any thing.
                }
            }
        }
```

Please help me. I'm new to it.

Comment: Why is there two `if let arr`? Don't use `NSDictionary`, use Swift Types. Does it pass the first test? If yes, `if let main = arr["main"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]` (array of dictionaries) should be the next logical step. Then `let val1 = main[0]["USDARS"] as? String`?

Comment: Hello it does not work

Comment: What doesn't work? You are ware that you are doing multiples "if" tests, but that any of them could fail? Which one exactly (you could add an "else" case)? Do you even pass the first one?

Comment: Use https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON. Its super easy to handle JSON in this.

Comment: Use SwiftJson as mentioned by @iAviator , its super easy to handle JSON using that library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in
        self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)
})

typealias JSONStandard = [String : AnyObject]

func parseData(JSONData : Data) {
    do {
        var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONStandard
        if let items = readableJSON["main"] as? [JSONStandard] {
            for i in 0..<items.count  {
                let item = items[i]
                    if let USDARS = item["USDARS"]
                        print(USDARS)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

To print a specific value, you can do it in two ways:

Make a new Alamofire request each time you search for something:

```
let whatToSearchFor: String = "13-02-2017"
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in
        self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)
})

typealias JSONStandard = [String : AnyObject]

func parseData(JSONData : Data) {
    do {
        var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONStandard
        if let items = readableJSON["main"] as? [JSONStandard] {
            for i in 0..<items.count  {
                let item = items[i]
                    guard item["date"] != nil else { print("nil"); return}
                    guard item["USDARS"] != nil else { print("nil"); return}
                    if item["date"] == whatToSearchFor {
                        print(item["USDARS"])
                    }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Create a dictionary with all values then print the searched one:

```
let dict = [String : String]

Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in
        self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)
})

typealias JSONStandard = [String : AnyObject]

func parseData(JSONData : Data) {
    do {
        var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONStandard
        if let items = readableJSON["main"] as? [JSONStandard] {
            for i in 0..<items.count  {
                let item = items[i]
                guard item["date"] != nil else { print("nil"); return}
                guard item["USDARS"] != nil else { print("nil"); return}
                let date = item["date"]
                let USDARS = item["USDARS"]
                dict[date] = USDARS
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
let whatToSearchFor: String = "13-02-2017"
print(dict[whatToSearchFor])
```

Edit after there is no "main" in JSON:

```
let whatToSearchFor: String = "13-02-2017"
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in
        self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)
})

typealias JSONStandard = [String : AnyObject]

func parseData(JSONData : Data) {
    do {
        var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONStandard
        if let items = readableJSON {
            for i in 0..<items.count  {
                let item = items[i]
                    guard item["date"] != nil else { print("nil"); return}
                    guard item["USDARS"] != nil else { print("nil"); return}
                    if item["date"] == whatToSearchFor {
                        print(item["USDARS"])
                    }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Or:

```
let dict = [String : String]

Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in
        self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)
})

typealias JSONStandard = [String : AnyObject]

func parseData(JSONData : Data) {
    do {
        var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONStandard
        if let items = readableJSON {
            for i in 0..<items.count  {
                let item = items[i]
                guard item["date"] != nil else { print("nil"); return}
                guard item["USDARS"] != nil else { print("nil"); return}
                let date = item["date"]
                let USDARS = item["USDARS"]
                dict[date] = USDARS
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
let whatToSearchFor: String = "13-02-2017"
print(dict[whatToSearchFor])
```

Basically `main` disappears and also `as? [JSONStandard]` because `readableJSON` is defined as `JSONStandard`.

Comment: Hello, if I want to print as per date for example : 13-02-2017  USDRS Value

Comment: How should I print for particular date with currency value.

Comment: Here it prints all values, due to for loop

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Also, added checking for nil values.

Comment: Hello I have updated my Question, please tell me how do I parse it.

Comment: So there is no "main"?

Comment: yes there is no main, now its in array

Comment: please help me this one.

Comment: Can you post the entire JSON, please?

Comment: I have updated my Question, its just 3 days record, like this there is 30 days record.

Comment: I will think about it when I get home, now I don't have my MacBook with me. Ok?

Comment: No problem. Anytime!

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: Anytime! Did it work?

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow. And inform you.

Comment: Ok, good luck !

Comment: Thanks a lot...!!!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [EVReflection](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection), you have to create 2 models and then you can easily manage the result.

Models:

```
class RootElementModel : EVObject{
    var main : [MainElement];
}

class MainElementModel : EVObject{
    var date : String = "";
    var USDARS : CGFloat = 0;
    var USDCLP : CGFloat = 0;
    var USDSDG : CGFloat = 0;
}
```

then you can use as below:

```
Alamofire.request("url").responseString{
response in
    let resString = response.result.value
    let items = RootElementModel(json : resString).main
    print("first item USDARS = \(items[0].USDARS)")
}
```

for more usage examples and installation tutorial you can read [Official Documentation](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection).